# Reduce aggregation query time

Tags: mongodb, lookup

I am a beginner in mongodb. I am working on two collections bookings and booking_logs. I have around 7k bookings and 14k booking_logs.

I want to get booking with their logs for which booking_logs exist with bookings. I have used the following query.

```
db.bookings.aggregate([
{$lookup:{
    "from":"booking_logs",
    "localField":"_id",
    "foreignField":"booking_id",
    "as":"booking_time_logs"
    }},
{"$match":{"booking_time_logs":{"$not":{"$size":0}}}}
])
```

But, the query is taking too much time to execute. Is there any way to reduce the time? Please answer. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Meanwhile, there are 2 underscores in `booking__logs`. Make sure that the collection name is correct. And also please revise your question, as you ask the question that is different with the question title.

Comment: Are `_id` & `booking_id` fields indexed?

Comment: @harshavmb, Yes, _id and booking_id fields are indexed.

Comment: @Yong Shun, collection name is booking_logs. Thank you! for correcting me.